# Not able to add appdelegate in object /// cocos 2d uikit integration

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I create a new cocos 2d project. I want to integrate ui kit in it. I have followed ray wendelich tutorial , on how to integrate uikit and cocs 2d.

I have completed his tutorial but when I create my own project. I am not able to add appdelegate class of object in the identity inspector.

As you can see in the image, there is no option for appdelegate (in the drop down list) for my object, but in raywenderlinch tutorial it is shown.

[image]

Comment: Xcode may not list some time you can directly type app delegate name(AppDelegate) over there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AppController` instead of `Appdelegate`. That tutorial is referring old cocos2d version.

In Cocos2d 2.0 onwards used AppController in place of Appdelegate.

Again don't know why Cocos2d team doing this kind of simple naming changes !!!