# AppDelegate not available in class list

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I'm trying to use UIKit in a cocos2d game by following Ray Wenderlichs tutorial: [How To Integrate Cocos2D and UIKit](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit)

However I'm stuck at this point:

> Then, select the new Object, go to the Identity Inspector, and set the
>   Class to AppDelegate.

The AppDelegate class doesn't appear as an option in the class list in the Identity Inspector, even though all my custom classes do. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: What happens if you just type it in?

Comment: It still doesn't find it, so I can't hook up the window later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in another post: [Not able to add appdelegate in object /// cocos 2d uikit integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443739/not-able-to-add-appdelegate-in-object-cocos-2d-uikit-integration?rq=1)

Use AppController instead of AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

I have answered similar question. Just restart XCode can walk you out that. But this way does not always work. You can have a try. Wish you luck.

Also you can just type that in to have a try.

Comment: Tried restarting Xcode, unfortunately it didn't work. Neither did just typing it in